# Pass multiple images between activities

Tags: android, arrays, image, arraylist

(https://github.com/NagaveniA/MultipleImagesUpload)
^
Currently using this from github as my exercise on handling multiple images.

This is my adapter:

```
public class finalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<finalAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<ImageModel> imageModels;

    public finalAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ImageModel> imageModels) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imageModels = imageModels;

    }

    @Override
    public finalAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.selected_image_list, viewGroup, false);
        return new finalAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(imageModels.get(position))//imageModels.get(position)
                .placeholder(R.color.codeGray)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.image);

        holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context, FullImageActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return imageModels.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my activity after click 'done'

```
public class finalImage extends Activity {

    ArrayList<ImageModel> imageModels;

    RecyclerView fselectedImageRecyclerView;
    finalAdapter finalAdapter;

    ImageView myImage, imageView;

    Button upload;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_final_image);

        fselectedImageRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.fselected_recycler_view);
        fselectedImageRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);

        ImagesActivity.imageList = new ArrayList<>();

        finalAdapter = new finalAdapter(this, imageModels);
        fselectedImageRecyclerView.setAdapter(finalAdapter);
    }
}
```

How do I place selected images to my recycleview on the second activity same as selected_recycler_view in activity_images?

Comment: You can check how to send a custom object list via Intent here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092612/pass-list-of-objects-from-one-activity-to-other-activity-in-android

Answer (score -1):

Create a Static Array and Add all images you want to share to second activity add and get that array in next activity
it is not a recommended method it is shortcut
if you want to do a Professional way than you can use
View Model ,
Event Bus ,

these are Recommended ways and easy to understand
Thanks

Comment: If possible please share links for event bus, thanks.