# Passing List into ListView using Intent in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, listview, android-intent

I want to pass a List of string into another activity and then display it in a ListView using Intent. I fugured out that I have to pass the List as a Array or Serializable.

```
val intent: Intent = Intent(this,SettingsActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("list",ArrayList<String>(resultsList) )
    startActivity(intent)
```

But I can't figure out exactly how to get it from the intent and display it in ListView

Comment: intent.getParcebleArrayList()?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 sections to your question

1. Passing a list via an intent
2. Show that list in a Recycler View
3. To pass the list you can either use the Parcelable/ Serializabl method or use  a library like Gson() to serialize and deserialize it
   [Stackover flow answer on passing lists from one activity to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092612/pass-list-of-objects-from-one-activity-to-other-activity-in-android)

2.To show that data you would need a Recycler View and show it on the screen
Here is an [article to get you started](https://medium.com/swlh/android-recyclerview-part-1-creating-a-simple-list-d84392c268b0)

Comment: Thanks a lot, do you have any other article about RecycleView, because this one seems to be very good but it has broken pictures in it and they don't sow up

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584424/simple-android-recyclerview-example Here is a stack overflow article

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview Also this codepath should help